# Infinite scroll with static page how does it work?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

This page on medium https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ uses infinite scroll, but when viewing source code, the html is there so it doesn't use ajax or am I mistaken ?

Comment: You have 12k reputation and you ask such a question?

Comment: depends on the subject :) If it's C# ...

Answer (score 0):

Open the network panel in your inspector and watch the requests roll in as you scroll down. It's just getting jpg images so it's likely that the html is already there and the scroll action causes an ansync request for the image and javascript plugs it into the appropriate divs.

Comment: @jmargolistv I check with google chrome dev already: the html was not there.